# Material UI : React Autocomplete component (controlled) and disableCloseOnSelect

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have a problem using the [Autocomplete component](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) provided by Material UI for React.js.

Here is what my component looks like :

```
<Autocomplete
        options={options}
        value={value}
        disableCloseOnSelect
        onChange={handleChange}
        limitTags={4}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name }
        renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Checkbox
              icon={icon}
              checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
              className={classes.checkbox}
              checked={selected}
            />
            {option.name}
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params}  variant="outlined" label={label} placeholder={label} />
        )}
        {...custom}
      />
```

I can't get the feature `disableCloseOnSelect` to function with a controlled component, as it does not prevent the list from closing after select... If I remove the props `value` and `onChange` everything works perfectly, but I need them for my project.

Does anybody have the same problem or see anything wrong with the way I am handling things ?

There is an issue that seems to match mine [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18305). In that case, could it be a bug ?

Comment: Can you create a live example that shows this? You can use https://codesandbox.io for example.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably caused by the mother component re-rendering. Autocomplete's state needs to be localised.
Here's a sandbox demonstration of the difference this makes:
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-wilson-zz59q?file=/src/App.js

It also has performance benefits.

Comment: Dont let your answer depend on external information.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30025722)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the review. This is a sandbox I made to demonstrate the effect. The essential part of the answer is there: mother component reloads, dropdown is obviously rendered in closed state.